# Laravel - Валидация и локализация массива (файлов)

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте.

Появилась необходимость проводить валидацию формы, в которой есть поля для загрузки множества файлов.

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Это поле обязательно, только если получаемое значение поля "type" равно 1.

Так как файлы передаются как массив, то логично настроить правила для них таким образом (с окончанием .*):

```
'files.*' => [ 'required_if:type,1', 'file', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,pdf'] // неправильные правила
```

Но здесь, не смотря на правило required_if, если отправить форму без файлов, то никакой ошибки не будет, поэтому его имеет смысл убрать.

```
'files.*' => [ 'file', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,pdf'], // правильные правила
```

Я пошел дальше и решил сделать еще одно правило, которое заодно проверяет, является ли поле массивом и ограничивающее количество принимаемых файлов.

```
'files' => [ 'required_if:type,1','array','max:10'], // правильные правила
```

Казалось бы - всё здорово, не так ли?

Но когда дело дошло до написания локализации полей (lang/fields.php), то появилась проблема:

Если записать локализацию поля так:

```
'files' => 'Файлы',
```

то:

- при ошибках правила **files.*** при любой ошибке непосредственной
  проверки файла, поле будут назваться files.0, files.1, files.2 и т.д.;
- при ошибках правила **files** все отображается нормально;

Если записать так:

```
'files' => [ '*' => 'Файл',],
```

то:

- при ошибках правила **files.*** все отображается нормально;
- при ошибках правила **files** вылезает ошибка:

  ErrorException: mb_strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Если записать так:

```
'files.*' => 'Файл',
```

то в любом случае все будет отображаться неправильно.

Собственно, спрашиваю вашего совета в том, как это побороть, может быть кто сталкивался.

Comment: А как вы хотите чтобы он выводил? Вполне логично как по мне выводит, показывает какой именно файл не верный, если вы загрузите 10 картинок, как понять в какой ошибка? Можете попробовать чисто в самом валидаторе изменить текст ошибки попробовать вместе с полем.

Comment: Ярослав, вы абсолютно неправильно поняли проблему. Будет странно, если пользователь увидит стандартное сообщение “Ошибка в поле “files.1””. Хотелось бы, чтобы ему показывалось что-то типо «ошибка в файле 1» (кстати, как подставить в сообщение название файла?). Так можно сделать, но тогда, если файлы вообще не будут загружены, попытка валидатора вывести название поля вызовет Exception.

Comment: Всё это можно сделать с помощью кастомного валидатора в котором вы сможете и указать название файла и текст сообщения какой захотите, но тогда по сути будете велосипед писать, такие же проверки как предоставляет фреймворк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задать сообщения об ошибках, как вам нужно, можно в Form Request для вашей формы. Соответственно вам нужно создать этот самый кастомный Form Request ([документация](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#form-request-validation)). Далее в нем вам доступен метод `messages()`. В нем, по аналогии с `rules()`, вы можете задать сообщения об ошибках для каждого поля в зависимости от правила, которое зафейлилось.

Конкретно в вашем случае Form request будет иметь примерно такой вид:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CustomFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        // Здесь может быть проверка прав доступа к форме
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'files'   => ['required_if:type,1', 'array', 'max:10'],
            'files.*' => ['file', 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,pdf'],
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        // Здесь кастомные сообщения для каждого типа ошибки и поля
        return [
            'files.required' => 'Не забудьте приложить файлы',
            // и т.д.

            'files.*.file'   => 'Должен быть файл',
            'files.*.mime'   => 'Не поддерживаемый формат',
        ];
    }
}
```

Собственно, это тоже есть в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#customizing-the-error-messages).

Comment: Спасибо, направили меня на нужное решение. Названия полей в FormRequest можно задать с помощью функции attributes()